# Loading JSON into C3.js using javascript express routes

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs, c3.js

I am trying to draw a graph using c3.js. I was able to follow the getting started so I know the module is working correctly, but I am having troubles with the graph not displaying when I try to use my own data.

I am taking data from a database and storing it like so:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  findDocuments(db, function(docs){
      //console.log(docs);
      exports.getData = function(){
        return docs;
      }
    db.close();
  });
});
```

I know for certain this works, it provides the following output in a long string:

```
[{"_id":"5885dc66c2ef160d2163fb79",
 "temperature":18,
 "humidity":27,
 "visibleLight":260,
 "irLight":255,
 "date":"2017-01-23T10:35:16+00:00",
 "epochtime":1485167716703}]
```

This data is then loaded into my view using index.js like so:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Dashboard', 
    allData: db.getData()
  });
})
```

According to these samples here: http://c3js.org/samples/data_json.html
I attempt to draw the graph:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    json: allData,
    keys: {
      x: 'date', // it's possible to specify 'x' when category axis
      value: ['temperature', 'humidity'],
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas here. Is it possible that your `c3.generate()` line of code is getting hit BEFORE the `router.get()` promise is resolved ? Just as a test, if you replace your `json: allData` with a hard-coded sample, does it work as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your missing definition of how your timestamp looks like. How should c3/d3 know what kind of pattern do you use?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
            //use xFormat to define how your pattern looks like
            xFormat: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00',
            json: [ 
                // your awesome data
            ],
            keys: {
                x: 'date',
                value: ['temperature', 'humidity'],
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                //use tick.format to change how your pattern
                //will look in your chart (maybe more user friendly)
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }
        }
});
```

Since your timezone offset looks pretty odd (`+00:00`) you should take a look at the [time formatting api](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) of d3 to get your desired pattern.